# Return Result from Select Query in stored procedure to a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm writing a stored procedure that currently contains only a `SELECT` query. It will be expanded to do a number of other things, which is why it has to be a stored procedure, but for now, it is a simple query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT name, occupation, position 
FROM jobs 
WHERE ...
```

I'm looking to return the results of this query to be used in C#. I want to add it to a list so that I can bind it to a GridView component.

I don't know how to go about this, though. If I have to insert it into a list after returning all selected data, then that's alright, I just need to know how to properly return the data so that I can do that.

If I can return it in a format that can be popped right into a list, though, that would be ideal.

Comment: Why does it have to be a list? Return a standard ADO.NET component (DataTable, DataReader) and bind your grid to it. There're plenty of tutorials online how to do this. E.g. do https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+ADO.NET+GridView+Bind you will see a lot of stuff like http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/ADO.net-Database/BindSqlDataReadertoGridView.htm

Comment: That would be a much better solution! I'll have to look into how to return those rows from the stored procedure though. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: Just look at the example in the second link - it does just that - opens connection, retrieves data and binds it to a GridView1. It uses SELECT query, but it is easily adjusted to handle stored procedure.

Comment: Yes I mean in the Stored Procedure code itself. I don't know if I'm supposed to use a RETURN on the SELECT query somehow, or ... I can't seem to find this.

Comment: No, if you want to return multiple rows (not a single value) the last command in your Stored Procedure should be a SELECT - that result would get returned to C# code.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In stored procedure, you just need to write the select query like the below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, Name 
    FROM Test
END
```

On C# side, you can access using Reader, datatable, adapter.

Using adapter has just explained by Susanna Floora.

Using Reader:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

command = new SqlCommand("TestProcedure", connection);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

List<Test> TestList = new List<Test>();
Test test = null;

while (reader.Read())
{
    test = new Test();
    test.ID = int.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString());
    test.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
    TestList.Add(test);
}

gvGrid.DataSource = TestList;
gvGrid.DataBind();
```

Using dataTable:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

command = new SqlCommand("TestProcedure", connection);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
connection.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
gvGrid.DataSource = dt;
gvGrid.DataBind();
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: I would add `reader.Close()`, sometimes an open reader causes exceptions in the following code.

Comment: This is just an example, however you should always clean up such things in finally block including sqlconnection.

Comment: Which of the two examples given is most efficient for larger Datasets?

Comment: DataBind is not available ?

Comment: If you are referring to DataBind() method of grid in above example then  it should be available in web project and not required in grid available in other projects like windows application.

Comment: Incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

 command = new SqlCommand("TestProcedure", connection);
 command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 connection.Open();

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

 gvGrid.DataSource = dt;
 gvGrid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DShp;Initial Catalog=abc;Integrated Security=True");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("data", con);

da.SelectCommand.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure;

DataSet ds=new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds, "data");
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["data"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing Parameters in Stored Procedure and calling it in C# Code behind as shown below?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(func.internalConnection);
var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CustomerPortalOrderDetails", conn);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customerId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Qid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = qid;
conn.Open();

// Populate Production Panels
DataTable listCustomerJobDetails = new DataTable();
listCustomerJobDetails.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, took me ages to find a simple solution.

Using ASP.NET MVC 5 and EF 6:

When you add a stored procedure to your `.edmx` model, the result of the stored procedure will be delivered via an auto-generated object called `yourStoredProcName_result`.

This `_result` object contains the attributes corresponding to the columns in the database that your stored procedure selected.

The `_result` class can be simply converted to a list:

```
yourStoredProcName_result.ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// GET: api/GetStudent

public Response Get() {
    return StoredProcedure.GetStudent();
}

public static Response GetStudent() {
    using (var db = new dal()) {
        var student = db.Database.SqlQuery<GetStudentVm>("GetStudent").ToList();
        return new Response {
            Sucess = true,
            Message = student.Count() + " Student found",
            Data = student
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @sachin welcome to stack overflow please provide some short description  so that op can understand better

Answer (score 0):

Building on some of the responds here, i'd like to add an alternative way. Creating a generic method using reflection, that can map any Stored Procedure response to a List. That is, a List of any type you wish, as long as the given type contains similarly named members to the Stored Procedure columns in the response.
Ideally, i'd probably use Dapper for this - but here goes:

```
private static SqlConnection getConnectionString() // Should be gotten from config in secure storage.
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = "it.hurts.when.IP";
            builder.UserID = "someDBUser";
            builder.Password = "someDBPassword";
            builder.InitialCatalog = "someDB";
            return new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
        }

        public static List<T> ExecuteSP<T>(string SPName, List<SqlParameter> Params)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                using (SqlConnection Connection = getConnectionString())
                {
                    // Open connection
                    Connection.Open();

                    // Create command from params / SP
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SPName, Connection);

                    // Add parameters
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(Params.ToArray());
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    // Make datatable for conversion
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dataTable);
                    da.Dispose();

                    // Close connection
                    Connection.Close();
                }

                // Convert to list of T
                var retVal = ConvertToList<T>(dataTable);
                return retVal;
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ConvertToList Exception: " + e.ToString());
                return new List<T>();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts datatable to List<someType> if possible.
        /// </summary>
        public static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(DataTable dt)
        {
            try // Necesarry unfotunately.
            {
                var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                    .Select(c => c.ColumnName)
                    .ToList();

                var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

                return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
                    {
                        var objT = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

                        foreach (var pro in properties)
                        {
                            if (columnNames.Contains(pro.Name))
                            {
                                if (row[pro.Name].GetType() == typeof(System.DBNull)) pro.SetValue(objT, null, null);
                                else pro.SetValue(objT, row[pro.Name], null);
                            }
                        }

                        return objT;
                    }).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to write data to list. Often this occurs due to type errors (DBNull, nullables), changes in SP's used or wrongly formatted SP output.");
                Console.WriteLine("ConvertToList Exception: " + e.ToString());
                return new List<T>();
            }
        }
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Big-al/4c1ff3ed87b88570f8f6b62ee2216f9f

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help:

Getting rows from DB:

```
public static DataRowCollection getAllUsers(string tableName) 
{
     DataSet set = new DataSet();
     SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
     comm.Connection = DAL.DAL.conn;
     comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     comm.CommandText = "getAllUsers";
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
     da.SelectCommand = comm;
     da.Fill(set,tableName);

     DataRowCollection usersCollection = set.Tables[tableName].Rows;
     return usersCollection;
}
```

Populating DataGridView from  DataRowCollection :

```
public static void ShowAllUsers(DataGridView grdView,string table, params string[] fields) 
{
    DataRowCollection userSet = getAllUsers(table);
    foreach (DataRow user in userSet)
    {
         grdView.Rows.Add(user[fields[0]],
         user[fields[1]],
         user[fields[2]],
         user[fields[3]]);
    }
}
```

Implementation :

```
BLL.BLL.ShowAllUsers(grdUsers,"eusers","eid","euname","eupassword","eposition");
```