# Execute stored procedure and return List<T> in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

New to .NET Core. My goal is to return list of employees from my database (as a list or dbset):

```
public class MyDataContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDataContext(DbContextOptions<MyDataContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList(int EmpId, int DeptId)
    {
       // here I want to call my stored procedure, pass two parameters and execute it
       // At this point I am getting error of null argument 
       using (var context = new MyDataContext(options))
       using (var command = new MYDataContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
       {
            command.CommandText = "myStoredProcedureName";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            context.Database.OpenConnection();

            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
            }
       }
    }
}
```

in `Startup.cs` I have included

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

And in `appsettings.json` I have my connection string

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
       "DefaultConnection": "Server=ser11; Database=myDb; User Id=user; Password=123; Trusted_Connection=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
   },
   "Logging": 
   {
       "LogLevel": 
           {
               "Default": "Information",
               "Microsoft": "Warning",
               "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
           }
   },
   "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

At the code line

```
 using (var context = new MyDataContext(options))
```

I get an error

> There is no argument given that correspond to the required formal parameter 'options'

Any idea what I should pass?

Comment: Where are the `options` being set in `GetEmployeeList`, is it global somewhere? I don't see them being passed into the function or set as a property in the constructor?

Comment: I have all the settings in Startup.cs and appsettings. It working good except for the above storeprocedure excute code.

Comment: if you have all saved you don't need to send in anything

Comment: thanks David,chrisbyte using (var context = new MyDataContext(options)) was not necessary and when I removed it all works good, thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

This is a method defined on a `MyDataContext`, so you don't need to create a new one.

Try this:

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList(int EmpId, int DeptId)
{
   using (var command = Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
   {
      command.CommandText = "myStoredProcedureName";
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      Database.OpenConnection();
      using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
      {

      }
   }
}
```

`Database` is a property of the current object i.e. `this`.

Comment: thanks, that is fixed now, but my list is returning null while I had records in my database and database is also Open. How do I pass multiple parameters to my s.procedure? And how do I read them to object class?

Comment: @MedhanieW. Have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: I am using ADO.NET style to read and map into an object class which i couldn't see in the documentation

Comment: If your using EF Core, you don't need the ADO.NET style code. EF does all the hard work for you through a simple `ToList()`. If you must use `SqlReader` there are **many** examples on the web. Here is one https://stackoverflow.com/a/18909963/8126362

Comment: @MedhanieW. Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
public class Employee
{
    // Column must match the column name returned by the stored procedure
    [Column("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column("LastName")]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}

public partial class MyDataContext: DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(entity =>
      {
        entity.HasNoKey();
      });
    }
}

public async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployeeList(int EmpId, int DeptId)
{
   return await Context.Set<Employee>()
                       .FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE dbo.myStoredProcedureName {EmpId} {DeptId}")
                       .ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList(int EmpId, int DeptId)
{

List<Employee> result = new List<Employee>();
using (var context = new MyDataContext(options))
using (var command = new MYDataContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "myStoredProcedureName";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    context.Database.OpenConnection();

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.NextResult())
        {
            result = new List<Employee>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(Populators.PopulateEmployee(reader));
            }
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
```